# planet+django makemigration does not work

Tags: django, python-3.x, syncdb, makemigrations

I am trying to use django-planet on python 3, django 1.9.  After following the instruction on their [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-planet) I get the following error after python manage.py makemigrations:

> planet.Feed.site: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model
>   'Site', whic h is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: 1.9 is not supported for django-planet. The maximum django version supported is 1.7.

Comment: thank you, is there any equivalent to django-planet that is compatible with django 1.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-planet's author here :)

I've noticed, thanks to your question, that docs are missing an step: you have to add `django.contrib.sites`to your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

After that, please run ´python manage.py migrate´ since Django 1.9 adds one migration to make `Site.domain` field unique.

I cant release yet a Django 1.9 compatible version for django-planet since `django-tagging` doesn't have an official release that supports it. But you can install the development version this way and your django-planet installation will work:

```
pip install -e git+git@github.com:Fantomas42/django-tagging.git@6246a1f270031908fe66cacbf1fb7a377021c4fc#egg=django-tagging
```